# Please add a link to meta.whatever.stackexchange.com on whatever.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

There's a link to "hot topics" on the right, but those link to individual posts, not to the list of posts. And there's a link to the general meta.stackexchange.com site (though it's not very prominent), possibly leading people to post questions there that might better be answered on the individual site's meta.

And of course by "whatever" I mean "any old Stack Exchange site, such as gaming.stackexchange.com or android.stackexchange.com", not literally "whatever.stackexchange.com"!

Comment: Without a screenshot with red free-hand circles I'll remain *whatever* on this FR.

Comment: Note there are navbar links on User Profile and Activity pages connecting the main and meta sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There already is... in two places.

Click on the Stack Exchange dropdown in the upper left corner and there it is...

[image: Meta link in SE dropdown]

And under help in the upper right corner:

[image: Meta link in Help Menu]

I think we've got it covered.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I just didn't look hard enough...